# Coefficients of Charpoly using Sympy in Python

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I am new to using the library Sympy. I am need to extract all coefficients of the characteristic polynomial to be used later.
For example, my code is:

```
    import sympy as sp
    M = sp.Matrix([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1], [1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
    lamda = symbols('lamda')
    p = M.charpoly(lamda)
    print(p)
    print(p.coeffs())
```

which gives output:

```
    PurePoly(lamda**6 + lamda**4 - lamda**2, lamda, domain='ZZ')
    [1, 1, -1]
```

However, I need [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], which includes the zero coefficients of the lamda too the exponents 4, 3, 1, and 0, terms. I would normally use a for loop to iterate over the equation to see which terms are missing so a zero can be inserted into the appropriate spot in the array of coefficients. However, when I attempted to do so, I received an error saying PurePoly type doesn't support indexing. So, I was wondering if anyone knows how to make sympy include the zeros or a way to do it myself? I need will eventually have to incorporate this code into a loop for lots of matrices so I can't manually do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When I have questions like this I hope for some sort of intelligent naming of methods for objects and look through the directory of the object:

```
>>> print([w for w in dir(p) if 'coeff' in w])
['all_coeffs', 'as_coeff_Add', 'as_coeff_Mul', ...]
```

That `all_coeffs` is the one you want:

```
>>> help(p.all_coeffs)
Help on method all_coeffs in module sympy.polys.polytools:

all_coeffs(f) method of sympy.polys.polytools.PurePoly instance
    Returns all coefficients from a univariate polynomial ``f``.

>>> p.all_coeffs()
[1,0,1,0,−1,0,0]
```

Comment: You could also look at `help(p)` and search for `coeff` (type `/coeff`). This will help you find not only methods whose name mentions "coeff" but also methods whose docstring mentions it.